# How do I check if a input (integer) matches another value (integer) that exits within my array?

Tags: java

I just learned about array and wanted to build a simple program where I use do-while loops to only accept numbers entered that exist in the array but I'm having some trouble see the problem

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] values; 
values = new int[5];
values[0] = 16;
values[1] = 10;
values[2] = 11;
values[3] = 14;
values[4] = 17;
    int value;
    do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        value = input.nextInt();    
    }
    while(value != values[]);
```

the rest was going to be "if" statements that contained some out going text based on the which numbers from the array are entered. The "while" condition comes up in an error in the way I entered it as

EDIT: Since this isn't possible in java could I just write !=16,10,11,14,17 without getting an error? The array won't work in the condition so I'm still stuck in figuring a way to including multiple numbers in the condition

Comment: "_The "while" condition comes up in an error_" Whenever you get errors or exceptions, you should post them in the question.

Comment: Hint: try writing a helper method that checks if an int is in an array, and use that in your loop condition.

Comment: Use Arrays.binarySearch() to search the value in values[], like in while(Arrays.binarySearch(values, value) < 0) ... as in my answer

Comment: ... or {}while(!values.contains(value)) but with a List of integers: List<Integer>   -- tested and updated solutions ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see it's **not possible** to just write ***while(value != values[])*** but you can search a value in an array or check if the value is contained in a List:

**--- First way**

Using a List of integers:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InArrayWithAsListContains {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value=0;
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        values.add(16);
        values.add(10);
        values.add(11);
        values.add(14);
        values.add(17);    

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            value = input.nextInt();    
        } while(!values.contains(value)); 
    }
}
```

A **variation** to work with a List starting with int[]:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {16,10,11,14,17};        

// int[] into List<Integer> conversion
for (int i : arr) values.add(i);
```

**--- Second way**

Just using arrays and Arrays.binarySearch(values, key)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value=0;
        int[] values = {16,10,11,14,17};

        Arrays.sort(values);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            value = input.nextInt();    
        } while(Arrays.binarySearch(values, value) < 0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: No it is not. If OP uses `int[]` (and he does that) then your idea will not work. And that you post code without testing it is very ... bad.

Comment: Your edit shows me that you have no idea what I'm talking about: this line `Arrays.asList(values).contains(value)` makes no sense with a primitive array. So take the time and test your code.

Comment: Thanks to point that @Tom, now the solution was updated and tested

Answer (score 5):

The termination condition of your `do` loop:

```
while(value != values[])
```

is not legal Java. You cannot compare an `int` value to an array and you cannot reference an array using `values[]`. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but you need to put in a specific subscript in the termination condition or modify it in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

An `int` is not the same thing as an `int[]`